# Allocated Memory difference in xen guests after using Linux 3+ kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, xen

Can someone explain to me why there is a memory difference in Guests with the same configuration?

- **Hypervisor**: xen 4.2 64 bit
- **VM1**: Centos 5.7 with 2.6.18-274.el5xen

Assigned memory from xen is exactly the same as memory inside guest, 524288k (512m):

```
free -k
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        524288     445004      79284          0      18040     182652
-/+ buffers/cache:     244312     279976
Swap:       524280          0     524280
```

despite showing:

```
" Memory: 500984k/524288k available (2533k kernel code, 23212k reserved, 1746k data, 196k init) "
```

`dmesg`: http://pastebin.com/FmVRniLJ

**Question1:**

Why does `free` show exact memory, while `dmesg` clearly showed 2.5MB for kernel code and 23MB as reserved?

- **VM2:** Ubuntu 12.04 ,3.2.0-48-

For the same resources Ubuntu 12.04 with pvopskernel is showing 501236k.

```
free -k
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        501236     147188     354048          0      12588      87668
-/+ buffers/cache:      46932     454304
Swap:            0          0          0
```

`dmesg`: http://pastebin.com/jgNfcxc5

```
Memory: 481820k/524288k available (6553k kernel code, 448k absent, 42020k reserved, 6642k data, 924k init)
```

**Question2:**

What might be the reason for this behavior, can this have something to do with  with pvops kernel, or is it because of changes in Linux 3.0+ Memory Management?

Comment: 1. What is the OS of your Dom0?
2. How can a CentOS and a Ubuntu DomU be "identical"?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5124/what-does-the-virtual-kernel-memory-layout-in-dmesg-imply

Comment: @Nils cenots is using xen kernel and ubuntu is using pvops kernel.

Comment: Is the crashkernel active within your centos? That would explain why it uses more memory. `dmesg|grep -i crash`

Comment: Crossposted on [SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/522892/allocated-memory-difference-in-xen-guests-with-linux-3-kernel)

Comment: @Nils it didnt return anything