# Virtual kernel memory layout in dmesg linux kernel 2.6.31

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, dmesg

I'm working on a embedded linux project for ARM architecture, kernel version is `2.6.31.12-rt21`. In `dmesg`, I cannot see the virtual kernel memory layout like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5124/what-does-the-virtual-kernel-memory-layout-in-dmesg-imply):

```
virtual kernel memory layout:
    fixmap  : 0xffc57000 - 0xfffff000   (3744 kB)
    pkmap   : 0xff800000 - 0xffa00000   (2048 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xf7ffe000 - 0xff7fe000   ( 120 MB)
    lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xf77fe000   ( 887 MB)
      .init : 0xc0906000 - 0xc0973000   ( 436 kB)
      .data : 0xc071ae6a - 0xc08feb78   (1935 kB)
      .text : 0xc0400000 - 0xc071ae6a   (3179 kB)
```

Did this feature (print virtual memory layout) is implemented in linux kernel version 2.6.31? And how to enable it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. This feature was already implemented on older versions of Linux like 2.4.37(link1). I could not track the exact time this was commited, neither config parameters to enable this output on dmesg. It should work out of the box, cause it does not seems to be a "tunnable". When `__init arm_add_memory` is called, it populates meminfo through `meminfo.nr_banks++(link2);` Im searching...

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/init.c?v=2.4.37  -  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c?v=2.6.39#L469

Comment: I've looked around, but did not see piece of code in 2 files you listed to do that. I found it in kernel version 3.14 but I don't know what exactly version of kernel begining show this information.