# Working my way through dmesg output on a custom 3.5.4 kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, memory

Having read this thread here:

[What does the Virtual kernel Memory Layout in dmesg imply?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5124/what-does-the-virtual-kernel-memory-layout-in-dmesg-imply)

It sounds like 'lowmem' is exclusively meant for kernel-space.

```
[    0.000000] virtual kernel memory layout:
fixmap  : 0xfffe3000 - 0xfffff000   ( 112 kB)
vmalloc : 0xe07c0000 - 0xfffe1000   ( 504 MB)
lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xdffc0000   ( 511 MB)
  .init : 0xc13f7000 - 0xc1447000   ( 320 kB)
  .data : 0xc12b4399 - 0xc13f6e20   (1290 kB)
  .text : 0xc1000000 - 0xc12b4399   (2768 kB)
```

In my case here, I have 512MB of ram in total in my system.  My question is:

If lowmem is meant only for kernel-space, and here that's 511MB, does that mean User-Space can only reach into 1MB?